# Set of normal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How can I possibly characterize the set of matrices such that $A^T A = A A^T$?

I know that if I have $A^T A = A A^T = I_n$ then it is the set of orthogonal matrices ($A^{-1}=A^T$). But now how can I describe such a set? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assuming that the matrices in question have real entries, $A^TA=AA^T$ iff $A$ is normal.

Comment: Why not just describe them by $A^TA=A^TA$? Do you want to know properties of such matrices, i.e., normal matrices? What do you really mean by "description"? The question is not particularly clear.

Comment: They are precisely the real matrix that are unitarily equivalent to a diagonal (possibly complex) matrix. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2843109/motivation-of-adjoints-and-normal-operators/2843450#2843450

Answer (score 1):

These are the so-called [normal matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix) (assuming that we are talking about real matrices here).